# Websockets redundant URL info?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Here is a web socket client.  Why do I need to enter `myURL` twice?  Would the server always listen on the same URL, where /socket.io/socket.io.js is?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='myURL:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('myURL:8888');

            socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
                $('#messages').append('<li>' + data.message + '</li>');

                socket.emit('i am client', {data: 'foo!'});
            });
            socket.on('time', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#messages').append('<li>' + data.time + '</li>');
            });
            socket.on('error', function() { console.error(arguments) });
            socket.on('message', function() { console.log(arguments) });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having any idea of how precisely you work with socket.io:

The first instance of 'myURL' is where you load the socket.io library. This is just a JavaScript file, which then gets executed in your browser.

The second instance is you establishing a connection to a socket endpoint. Here you need to give the URL + port combination at which the server listens.

These two may be connected, e.g. because the script is hosted by a the server you want to connect to (as seems to be the case here), but they don't need to be.

The script could e.g. be loaded from the local filesystem, while the server is run on another machine. In this case, there would not be a reoccurence of the URL.

Comment: Does the socket.io.js have to be custom-generated for the particular nodeJS backend?  OR would one socket.io.js script work for all nodeJS backends?

Comment: The JavaScript library is not backend-specific.